# renew oAuth tokens on Android without opening a webview

Tags: android, security, oauth, twitter-oauth, facebook-oauth

I'm building an app that will integrate with facebook, twitter, instagram, g+, youtube.
The google services is simple as I can ask for a token to the AccountManager (or even simpler the GoogleAccountManager) and ask for a token via `AccountManager.get(this).getAuthTokenByFeatures(...)` if it's the first time, it will prompt the user to authorise and all further access the AccountManager will deal with any token renew, etc and just give me back the token.

But for WebView based authentications (facebook, twitter, instagram) I'm doing the commonly popular method of opening a webview, let the user authorise it, use localhost as the redirect_url and use a WebViewClient to intercept the call, capture the token, and finish the webview.

Up to this point everything is working fine!

The problem I'm facing is that tokens expire! That way after a token expires there will be another popup of the webview, the service will load, hopefully immediately authorise (because the service remembers that the user already authorised it), redirect to localhost and the WebViewClient intercept and close it.

So now imagine the user coming back to an app after a week or so without using it and see several little quick pop up in a row? Terrible user experience to say the least.

Any ideas on how to handle that ????

Comment: AFAIK, twitter tokens do not expire in general; Facebook tokens do, however. There is however a facebook request to renew/extend the token. You can use an Alarm to renew the token daily. I am not aware of instagram apis.

Comment: The simple solution is to only display a request if there already isn't one pending.

Comment: @SherifelKhatib I forgot to include in the post that I'm aware of the facebook.renew (my bad), but to make the problem more explicit I included fb. I saw twitter popping the authorisation window on my dev phone the other day (after weekend). I'll keep an eye open for it. I asking more if there's some platform wide technique that I could use to renew tokens.